# How can I stop GmailApp.SendEmail() from sending emails to the recipient AND the current user running the script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to send emails programmatically from Google Sheets, using Google Apps Script-- specifically the GmailApp.SendEmail() function.

The problem is that each email the script sends to the designated recipient is also sent to the current user running the script.

Is there a setting that I could deactivate to stop sending emails to the current user?

I have not been able to find any documentation on why this might be happening so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Snippet of code from comment:

```
function sendEmailTest() { 
  var email = "[INSERT EMAIL]"; 
  var title = "Hello"; 
  var message = "testing 123"; 
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, title, message); 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the snipped of code that shows where you send the email?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Here is a simplified example of how I am using the function:

function sendEmailTest() {
  var email = "[INSERT EMAIL]";
  var title = "Hello";
  var message = "testing 123";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, title, message);
}

Regardless the variables I pass in, I still have the same problem that, as the sender, I am sent a duplicate of the email I sent out.

Comment: The code you posted will not send duplicate emails. I wasn't able to replicate your error. How are you creating your email string?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with Google Apps for Work setup? Is it possible that my gmail could be set up to cc all activity to my own email? Right now, I am getting the email string from an array of cells in a spreadsheet